# Wi-fi problem Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

I have BCM4313 802.11bgn wireless network adapter (rev 01), with is not recognized on Ubuntu 14.04. What to do?

Comment: Did you check if there is a hard or soft block on your device? You can issue "rfkill list all" command to do so.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110 Follow the instructions and post again if they dont work

Answer (score -1):

This device uses the driver combination `bcma` and `brcmsmac`. It shouldn’t be necessary to install anything at all. Required firmware is installed by default in the package `linux-firmware`. In a few cases, it is necessary to blacklist `b43` and `ssb`. Running the following commands would do this:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist b43" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist ssb" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

This sorts the issue for me.

---

Source: [Post by chili555 on Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110&s=a0d86031fa77624fed9c66028b6cb13b&p=12972388#post12972388)